# Than ever before VS. than it ever has been

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the difference between:

> Cybercrime would be up in 2020, higher **than ever before**

Vs.

> Cybercrime would be up in 2020, higher **than it ever has been**

Sentence1 is what I always use, but sentence2 seems the same(a native English speaker used this format)

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mean the same, as **before** refers to all the events that have happened before this moments, and **ever has been** also refers to the same.
Although, I personally think that the latter put more emphasis on the meaning.